# How can I get TfidfVectorizer in a pipeline? Concatenation axes don't match

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to get a TfidfVectorizer working in a Pipeline, but the pipeline generates an error that the concatenation axes don't match. The TfidfVectorizer seems to work correctly when called outside the pipeline, which is very simple at the moment.  Here's code that will generates the error.

```
    text_features = data.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns
    numeric_features = data.drop(['target'],axis=1).select_dtypes(include=['int64','int32']).columns
    numeric_transformer = StandardScaler()
    text_transformer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df = 5)    
    preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
        transformers = [
            ('text', text_transformer, text_features),
            ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features) #errors are the same even if I comment this out.
            
        ])
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data.drop(['target'], axis=1), 
                                                    data['target'], 
                                                    random_state=0)

    pipe = Pipeline(steps = [
        ('preprocessor',preprocessor),
        ('SVC', SVC(C = 10000))])
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data.drop(['target'], axis=1), 
                                                    data['target'], 
                                                    random_state=0)
    text_transformer.fit(X_train[text_features]) # does not produce error
    preprocessor.fit(X_train) #produces error (see below.)
```

Here's the error message, a ValueError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-248-bd1982955a12> in <module>
----> 1 func()

<ipython-input-247-d2024ad1ac0c> in func()
     24                                                     random_state=0)
     25     text_transformer.fit(data['text'])
---> 26     preprocessor.fit(X_train)
     27 
     28     print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in fit(self, X, y)
    492         # we use fit_transform to make sure to set sparse_output_ (for which we
    493         # need the transformed data) to have consistent output type in predict
--> 494         self.fit_transform(X, y=y)
    495         return self
    496 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    551         self._validate_output(Xs)
    552 
--> 553         return self._hstack(list(Xs))
    554 
    555     def transform(self, X):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in _hstack(self, Xs)
    637         else:
    638             Xs = [f.toarray() if sparse.issparse(f) else f for f in Xs]
--> 639             return np.hstack(Xs)
    640 
    641     def _sk_visual_block_(self):

<__array_function__ internals> in hstack(*args, **kwargs)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py in hstack(tup)
    343         return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)
    344     else:
--> 345         return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)
    346 
    347 

<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 1 and the array at index 1 has size 4179
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficulty is created by the first line,

```
text_features = data.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns
```

which returns pandas index object.

Checking the [docs for ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html), we discover that for the columns argument, " A scalar string or int should be used where transformer expects X to be a 1d array-like (vector), otherwise a 2d array will be passed to the transformer."

In order to select multiple columns by name or dtype, we need to use [make_column_selector](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.make_column_selector.html#sklearn.compose.make_column_selector). It's simple: just pass the index object to make_column_selector and everything will be okay:

```
from sklearn.compose import make_column_selector

...

('text', text_transformer, make_column_selector(text_features))
```

Alternatively, if you have stable names for your columns, you can pass the names of the columns in multiple steps in the pipe. Less flexible, but possibly more readable.